# Time Complexity of this program solving the coin change problem

Tags: python, loops, recursion, iteration, time-complexity

I have created a program shown below, and I am confused as to how to figure out its time complexity. Is it O(n<sup>target/min(coins)</sup>) because a for loop is created each time the function is called, and the function is called `target/min(coins)` times?

The program solves the coin change problem (although not in a very efficient way!):

You are given an array of coins with varying denominations and an integer sum representing the total amount of money; you must return the fewest coins required to make up that sum.

For this problem

Code:

```py
def count(coins: list[int], target):
    def helper(coins, target, vals = [], answers = set()):
        if target<0:
            vals.pop()
        elif target==0:
            vals.sort()
            answers.add(tuple(vals))
            vals.clear()
        else:
            for coin in coins:
                helper(coins, target-coin, vals+[coin])
            return len(answers)
        
    coins.sort()
    if (answer:=helper(coins, target)): 
        return answer
    else:
        return -1

print(count([2, 5, 3, 6], 10)) # 5
print(count([1, 3, 5, 7], 8)) # 6
```

Attempt at code explanation (explained for print statement 2):

It starts with finding the most amount of coins that is needed to reach the target or go higher( `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)` in this case).

From there it iterates over all the possible values for the last row (`(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)`, `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)`, `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7)`). If the sum of the numbers is negative, it removes that value and tries again with a different value.

It adds any solutions (where `sum(vals)==target`)to the set `answers` (after sorting it) to prevent duplicates from being counted.

Then it moves to the higher row (`(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3)`, `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5)`, `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7)`). And repeats.

Can anyone explain what is the time complexity of the program along with why? Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you *think* the complexity is and why?

Comment: @ScottHunter I added what I think it is. I am just not sure if I am approaching it the right way.

Comment: Shouldn't the complexity have *something* to do with the number of coins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have realized that my initial thought was correct: the time complexity is indeed O(n<sup>ceil(target/min(coins))</sup>).

If you take the smallest value in coins, then it will have to call itself `ceil(target/min(coins))` times, and with each call start a new for loop, which is an O(n) operation. Therefore, it becomes O(n<sup>ceil(target/min(coins))</sup>) time complexity